# Como impedir movimentar o cursor num jFormattedTextfield com máscara?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um campo formatado da seguinte forma: '### ### ###'

Quando clico no campo que contém essa máscara às vezes o cursor fica-me no meio ou no sítio onde clico.

Exemplo: '##|# ### ###'

Há alguma forma de impedir que o cursor possa ser alterado de sítio ao clicar no campo?

Answer (score 1):

Verifica este código:

(não foi testado)
[1º parte]

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
                int offset = tf.viewToModel(e.getPoint());
                tf.setCaretPosition(offset);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

[2ºparte]

```
 MeteONomeDoTeujFormattedTextfield.addMouseListener(ml);
```

O link da fonte é [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201873/jformattedtextfield-caret-position-on-focus)

Comment: Ainda sou novo nestas andanças, como é que aplico essa função ao meu JFormattedTextField ? é no evento on mouseClicked do meu JFormattedTextfield? Já vi obrigado ;) vou testar

Comment: Também dava por aí, só para tentar por a funcionar, tenta colar no construtor a primeira parte, depois logo a seguir chamas o nome do teu 'JFormattedTextField'e colas a segunda parte...

Comment: Mesmo no construtor não funciona :s